# How to set focus not on the UITextView when it is shown?

Tags: ios, focus, uitextview, soft-keyboard

In some cases when the `UITextView` in shown, I want it does not show focus and soft keybaord, **when user clicks on it, both will show**.

But in some other cases, I want the focus and soft keybaord shown when the `UITextview` is shown.

I know how to show the focus but I don't know how to let UItextview lose focus.

Any help is appreciated. thank you!

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
if(isEditMode) {
   [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
} else {
   [self.textView resignFirstResponder];
}
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITextView is a subclass of UIResponder.

To make text view first responder (get focus) use:

```
textView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

To make text view resign first responder (loose focus) use:

```
textView.resignFirstResponder()
```

Comment: I tried but does not work for me, when I resignFirstResponder the textView still get the focus and show the keyboard.

Comment: I find a interesting thing is that when I first show the UITextView it does not get focus and only if I single tap it in get focus then it will show focus all the rest time.

Comment: @newszer Check that textView property is not nil.

Comment: Regarding UITextView behavior - its actually intended. By default text view is not focused on appearance, but if you hide and then show view controller it belongs to, system remembers that you left screen with focus and automatically restores it.

Comment: Are there any way to not restore it?

Comment: You can call [textView resignFirstResponder] in viewWillDisappear:.